# Facebook OAuth Graph API v2 - Mandatory permissions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, oauth-2.0

I'm working on an app that needs the Facebook scope *post on your behalf* permission to work.
Will the upcoming version 2 of the Facebook Graph API allow developers to make permissions mandatory or will a user still have the option to *skip* a permission?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should have been a google query.

Comment: Actually I made a lot of research and didn't find any info. I was writing a question in here about this and just got this one as suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a simple google search you can find this info:

> Facebook Login in v2.0 contains significant differences as compared
>   with the previous version. At a high level, these changes include:
>
> - Permissions are now optional for people using your app. The Login
>     Dialog now lets people choose what info they share with your app.
>     People can disable what they share on a permission-by-permission
>     basis.
> - The list of friends is no longer part of the default list of
>     permissions and only returns the friends using the app. See the
>     section above on user IDs and friends to learn more about how IDs and
>     friends are changing.
> - basic_info has been replaced by public_profile.
>     The default permission set called basic_info has been replaced by
>     public_profile. The permission set is the same, aside from the fact
>     that list of friends has been moved to a separate permission.
> - There
>     have been significant changes to permissions. Most notably, all of the
>     friends_* permissions have been removed. Two new permissions have been
>     added as well. Please see the section below on permissions for more
>     information.
> - We now review some apps using Facebook Login. If your app
>     is asking for more than public_profile, email and user_friends we now
>     require your use of those permission to be reviewed by Facebook before
>     those permissions can be requested from regular users. Please see our
>     section below on review for more information.

In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

So answering your question yes, users can skip/revoke permissions whenever they want